# Calculated column not working in SharePoint 2010

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I am using nested IF statements with And, OR. It is working in excel, but when I transfer it over to SharePoint all values show as "no". 
I need this calculated column to look at values in column "Type of Request" and "Internal Priority". Any ideas why this is not working?

```
=IF(AND(OR([Type of Request] ="Adhoc",[Type of Request]="Issue/Research"),[Internal Priority]=1),"3 Days",IF(AND(OR([Type of Request]="Adhoc",[Type of Requst]="Issue/Research"),[Internal Priority]=2),"5 Days",IF(AND(OR([Type of Request]="Adhoc",[Type of Request]="Issue/Research"),[Internal Priority]=3),"10 Days",IF(AND(OR([Type of Request]="Enhancement/Maintenance",[Type of Request]="New Scheduled Report Request",[Type of Request]="Project"),[Internal Priority]=1),"30-60 Days",IF(AND(OR([Type of Request]="Enhancement/Maintenance",[Type of Request]="New Scheduled Report Request",[Type of Request]="Project"),[Internal Priority]=2),"60-90 Days")))))
```

Comment: What is the column type?

Answer (score 1):

First, the example you provided has a typo: one of the [Type of Request] items is misspelled.

But I'm guessing that you have Internal Priority set as a single line of text which will cause the comparisons to fail. Change it to a number data type.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I did see the typo, but also found my error.

The Priority column is a dropdown/choice column. I needed quotes around the values in the formula.

So the correct formula looks like this:

```
=IF(AND(OR([Type of Request] ="Adhoc",[Type of Request]="Issue/Research"),[Internal Priority]=”1”),"3 Days",IF(AND(OR([Type of Request]="Adhoc",[Type of Request]="Issue/Research"),[Internal Priority]=”2”),"5 Days",IF(AND(OR([Type of Request]="Adhoc",[Type of Request]="Issue/Research"),[Internal Priority]=”3”),"10 Days",IF(AND(OR([Type of Request]="Enhancement/Maintenance",[Type of Request]="New Scheduled Report Request",[Type of Request]="Project"),[Internal Priority]=”1”),"30-60 Days",IF(AND(OR([Type of Request]="Enhancement/Maintenance",[Type of Request]="New Scheduled Report Request",[Type of Request]="Project"),[Internal Priority]=”2”),"60-90 Days")))))
```